# How to create the emulator in Android studio 1.2.2 with API 23 in Linux?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using the Android Studio version 1.2.2 and update the api level as 23. Before i am using the api 19, i can create the emulator and run the project. While update the api level in my Android Studio and try to create the emulator that time i am getting this error. I am using the Linux OS.

** Below code **

```
ERROR: 32-bit Linux Android emulator binaries are DEPRECATED, to use them
       you will have to do at least one of the following:
       - Use the '-force-32bit' option when invoking 'emulator'.
       - Set ANDROID_EMULATOR_FORCE_32BIT to 'true' in your environment.
       Either one will allow you to use the 32-bit binaries, but please                       be aware that these will disappear in a future Android SDK release.
       Consider moving to a 64-bit Linux system before that happens.
```

Comment: if your computer is running a 64-bit OS you should download the correct images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can resolve this issue by updating the emulator configuration

1. Go to Run -> Edit Configuration menu in Android Studio
2. Select the app name under Android Application on the left pane
3. Select Emulator tab on the right pane
4. Tick "Additional command line options:" and enter `-force-32bit` in the text box next to it
5. Select "OK" and try to Run the app again.

Also you can try the below

1. In your terminal type `nano .profile`
2. Add `export ANDROID_EMULATOR_FORCE_32BIT=true` at the end of the file,save and exit
3. Run `source .profile` or simply exit your terminal and restart it, for changes to take effect.

Try to run your emulator.

NOTE: It is highly recommended that you install a 64bit operating system to continue your Android development because Google will eventually remove the 32bit binaries which will cause your emulator to stop working.

Comment: i did the above you mention steps, but i click the run button to launch the emulator that time i am getting the same error

Comment: What else are you getting , any stacktraces would be handy .

Comment: i am using the 32-bit, this error only i am getting.

Comment: Which Linux OS are you using ?

Comment: Updated my answer.Please check.

Comment: In your updated answer i done 3 steps and start try to launch the emulator this time also i am getting this same error. In 3rd step i run the source. profile  but nothing happen.

Comment: ANDROID_EMULATOR_FORCE_32BIT: command not found
 while run source.profile file i am getting this error

Comment: i checked Radix but still i am facing the same probem